# laravel - maatawebsite 3.1 export, Query gives empty excel with join

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have read the `https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html` documentation and it says not to use get(), but couldn't find a relevant piece of code of how to go about when it comes to DB:: and join. Please guide me on how should I do it under query. What should I replace get() with and if db::raw then how should be the syntax? An example would be of great help to me and others like me.

following is query in the export.php file

```
public function query()
{ 
    $this->complaints = DB::table('complaints')
   ->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'complaints.customer_id')
   ->join('technicians', 'technicians.id', '=', 'complaints.technician_id')
   ->select(DB::raw('complaints.*' , 'customers.first_name','customers.last_name',
   'customers.number', 'customers.email_address', 'customers.occupancy_name',
   'customers.building_number', 'customers.house_number',
   'customers.taluka', 'customers.city', 'customers.address', 'customers.package',
   'customers.package_date', 'customers.package_status', 
   'customers.package_period','technicians.first_name as t_fname', 'technicians.last_name as t 
   _lname','technicians.number as t_number'))

   ->where( function ( $query ) 
   {
        $query->where( 'customers.package', '=' ,"Platinum" )
        ->where(DB::Raw('timediff(now(), complaints.date )') ,'>', '06:00:00')
        ->where('complaints.status', '=', "Assigned");

   })
   ->orWhere( function ( $query )
   {
        $query->where( 'customers.package', '=' ,"Gold" )
        ->where(DB::Raw('timediff(now(), complaints.date )') ,'>', '24:00:00')
        ->where('complaints.status', '=', "Assigned");

    })
   ->orWhere( function ( $query )
   {
        $query->where( 'customers.package', '=' ,"Silver" )
        ->where(DB::Raw('timediff(now(), complaints.date )') ,'>', '48:00:00')
        ->where('complaints.status', '=', "Assigned");

   })
  ->get(); 
}
```

works finw when i do

```
public function query()
{
    return Complaints::query();
}
```

but how to do this with DB and joins with get in 3.1 version of maatwebsite.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the query in a sql ide? maybe it's empty?

Comment: it's giving me correct data, as needed only in export it is not working.